# Kill all sleeping mysql pool connections using node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, connection-pooling

I am using node for my project and using connection pooling, whenever I query `show processlist` I found more than 200 sleep connections even though i am releasing it after every query like this-

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    sql.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            conn.release();
            reject(err)
        }
        conn.query('QUERY', function (err, rows) {
            conn.release();
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
            else {
                resolve(rows[0])
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Still i found 200 plus sleep connections. Is there any way to kill useless sleeps connection through node? Or is it fine having so many sleep connections?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using connection pooling, you will need to [close all the connections in the pool](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#closing-all-the-connections-in-a-pool) when you're finished using them.  Otherwise the connections will stay open until they are closed by the MySQL server.

```
pool.end(function (err) {
  // all connections in the pool have ended
});
```

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1486) explains a little more about the nuance between releasing a connection (`conn.release()`) and closing the underlying connection pool (`pool.end()`).

Comment: But I cannot close my pool connections, because if i did, nothing will work as it is a live server

Comment: You would want to end the pool at least when the application ends under any condition.  Otherwise all those connections remain open after you stop the server.  Also what is your pool `connectionLimit` set at?

Comment: For now I have not set any limit

Comment: Do you start and stop your node server every so often?  Every time you do that, it's leaving all the connections it had open.

Comment: Yes, I do start stop often